# 1967: Philosophy

Tags: derrida

I am cataloguing "**papers**", "**books**", "**ideas**", "**insights**"... in Philosophy which become available in **1967**.
Are you aware of some? If yes, please, share author, what {"paper", "book", "ideas", "insight",...}, and the source.
I appreciate your help. **Thank you**. *It would be a plus if you could link one of the references you share with your life, please*.

Comment: I have no idea at all what this question is about.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the feedback. Have a nice day.

Comment: You can read about the Situationists here, and two books of 1967, by Guy Debord, and Raoul Vaneigem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situationist_International  The idea of sexual liberation in France may be a little underplayed in the article, sexual liberation to the students was a big issue, but sexuality itself had already been through a "recoupment". Made safe to serve consumption, commodified, even before the "revolution" even started.

Comment: Sex sells, but so does Green, green products for example, which may not be so good for the environment :):). So even a movement to change things is immediately captured, and "sold", "green" t-shirts and etc. Sex had already been captured before the uprising of '68 imo.

Comment: What you shared is interesting indeed. Thank you. I will get more knowledge on that path.

Answer (score 3):

1 A. Quinton, 'Political Philosophy' (Oxford Readings in Philosophy), was published in 1967 and showed how political philosophy, which in the years leadng up to its publication, had been much neglected in mainstream philosophy was a proper and respectable part of the subject.

2 Mary Warnock, 'Existentialist Ethics', London : Macmillan, 1967, gave me a first clear idea of what existentialism was.

3 Pamela Huby, 'Greek Ethics', London : Macmillan, 1967, widened my knowledge of Greek ethics to other philosophers besides Plato.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The books you mentioned are worth of further exploration. Thank you. Did you stumble in something "really" new regarding 1967, please?

Comment: It's a long while back. Let me think about it and I'll get back to you. Best - Geoff

Comment: Derrida's 'Grammatology' appeared in French in 1967. Though it made no impression on me at the time, it is clearly a work of philosophical importance and it belongs to' your' year.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I used Grammatology as an event. Today I found another one. Manabe, Syukuro, and Richard T. Wetherald (1967). "Thermal Equilibrium of the Atmosphere with a Given Distribution of Relative Humidity." J. Atmospheric Sciences 24: 241-59.

Comment: [One valuable example of this crossover of interests was a calculation published by Princeton computer specialists in 1967. They had managed to produce a model that simulated something roughly like the actual climate of the planet, with deserts and sea ice and trade winds in all the right places. Out of curiosity they doubled the amount of CO2 in their simulated atmosphere. The simulated global temperature rose a couple of degrees.]. It seems it was a very important paper to understand "climate".